# Set date in single line edit on opening

Tags: date, powerbuilder

I'm using PowerBuilder 10.5 and I have two single line edit (SLE) fields - `sle_date1` and `sle_date2` on my window.

What I need is for those two fields to be filled once I open my program. `sle_date2` has to have the value of today (for example - 09.07.13), and `sle_date1` has to have the value of (`sle_date2`-30 days) (example 09.06.13).

So, as I said, once I open my programs both fields would be filled immediately with values of today's date and the date of a month before.

How could I do that? Any advice just to get me going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can add some code to populate the edits in the `open()` event of your window
- with a given date that can be `today()`, you can compute a new date plus / minus a number of days with `RelativeDate()`

The following code just answers your question (though it could be better to use some `editmask` controls instead of `singlelineedit` as it would ease the handle of user's input):

```
date ld_now, ld_previousmonth
string ls_datefmt

ls_datefmt = "dd.mm.yy"
ld_now = today()
sle_1.text = string(ld_now, ls_datefmt)
ld_previousmonth= RelativeDate(ld_now, -30)
sle_2.text = string(ld_previousmonth, ls_datefmt)
```

It shows `09.07.13` and `09.06.13` at this time.

Comment: hi. I need to ask one more thing - two sle fields are writable so the client can write other then default dates. How can I set a condition that the difference between date1 and date2 is maximum one year or 365 days?

Comment: there is often multiple ways to make things in computing... I would add a function in the window to compute the date difference and display a message if the difference is too high. To call the function map an event to the `pbm_enchange` event for both sle fields in which you call your function. You can also map `pbm_enmodified` event if you want to react at each character typed .

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This is what I've done and it works fine.. "IF ld_2>=RelativeDate(ld_1, 366) THEN" where ld_1 and ld_2 are date variables that obtain the sle_1 and sle_2 text.

Comment: I've been looking at date pickers as they seem somewhat better for date manipulation then single line edit, but I can't seem to set dp_1 field as (dp_2-30days). Is it even possible to do that as I've seen that the date picker text property cannot be set in the painter and should not be set in script. ?

Comment: @JohnBlue: for datepicker, you have to use `GetValue()` and `SetValue()` with a date type (you can get the text with `GetText()`. For your problem, it could be interesting to use the properties `MinDate` and `MaxDate` to prevent the user to enter a date too old.

Comment: Thanks for the  advice, this is how it worked for me "DateTime dt_od//
dt_od=Datetime(today())//
dp_dat_do.SetValue(dt_od)//
dp_dat_od.value = datetime(Relativedate(dp_dat_do.datevalue, -30))//"

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to open your window. You can to this with put this code in your application open event (let suppose that your window is w_main):

```
open(w_main)
```

After that in put this code in your window's open event:

```
sle_date1.text  = string(today())
sle_date2.text  = string(RelativeDate(Today(), -30))
```

I think this solves your problem. Here is a little help for RelativeDate:

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.pocketbuilder_2.0.pkpsref/html/pkpsref/pkpsref662.htm

Best Regards
Gábor

Comment: Your direct usage of function calls inside `string()` without temporary variable makes the code more difficult to trace. Moreover you call `today()` twice which *could* lead to get 2 different dates. Of course it will probably not occur with `today()` but if one use datetimes or times with `now()` it could result with strange results...